# Compose - How to change color of date picker?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I currently moved over to material 3 in my app and am updating my date pickers. I'm able to change color of everything except for one text, the text that opens the year picker. Does anyone know how to change that field?
I've tried setting all colors of Datepicker colors = DatePickerDefaults.colors().
I've tried wrapping the datepicker in a MaterialTheme and set all the colors of colorScheme = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.copy(). Nothing seems to change it

[[image: What picker looks like]]

As described in post

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution provided which set the `Color.Red` using `setTextColor` method.

```
val datePicker = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.datePicker()
    .setTextColor(Color.Red)
    .build()
```